# circle image in cell imageView and how to resize it?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have in a ViewController tableView with the identifier "Cell". This is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    var url = NSURL(string: postCover[indexPath.row])
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check

    cell.imageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true

    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
    cell.textLabel?.text = postTitle[indexPath.row]

    cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius =  20
    cell.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true;

    return cell
}
```

So, `cornerRadius` works, but one of the problem is that my image in the cell(`cell.imageView?.image`) height is equal to row height and I cannot change neither height, nor width of this cell image.

When I try

```
cell.imageView?.frame.size.width = 100
```

nothing changes. Who knows, what is the problem?

And as I cannot control my image height and width I get as result rectangle with the border radius, but I want to have a square(w: 100, h: 100).

Comment: What do you want actually, a circular image or square?

Comment: Try using `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @AnilVarghese circular. I did explain just that now I get rectangle with the border radius. So I must have square to use cornerRadius and to get circular image

Comment: @VNJ no, I set already a height of rows. I want for example: my rows height = 100, but the image height and width inside of cell will: height: 80, width: 80

Comment: Can we see a screenshot of the screen to have  a clear idea?

Comment: @AnilVarghese I just added it to the question

Comment: You can create an UIImage extension to return a squared Image at the appropriate size. If you want the image to be at the left edge you need to create a custom cell

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus my cell has a custom style

Comment: that doesn't look to me like a custom cell

Comment: Do you want me to post a method to crop the longest side of your image to make it square and circle also if you want

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus yes, please!

Comment: The extension you can place it in the same file of you view controller class. put it at the bottom

Answer (score 4):

You can use this extension to crop the longest side of your image and return a squared UIImage:

```
extension UIImage {
    var squared: UIImage {
        let square = size.width < size.height ? CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.width) : CGSize(width: size.height, height: size.height)
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: square))
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        imageView.image = self
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.bounds.size)
        imageView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return result
    }
    var circle: UIImage {
        let square = size.width < size.height ? CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.width) : CGSize(width: size.height, height: size.height)
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: square))
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        imageView.image = self
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = square.width/2
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.bounds.size)
        imageView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return result
    }
    func resizeToWidth(width:Int)-> UIImage {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(ceil(CGFloat(width)/size.width * size.height)))))
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = self
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.bounds.size)
        imageView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return result
    }

}
```

Comment: thamk you and sorry, how can I use this extension?

Comment: yourImage.circle or yourImage.squared

Comment: You can also reduce size if you want. How many pixels do you want your image thumbnail to be ?

Comment: I put it to the bottom of the file and it prints the next error: `Declaration is only valid at file scope`

Comment: yourImage.resizeToWidth(128).circle

Comment: all the way at the bottom out of the class

Comment: or Just add a new file iOS swift source file to your project and name it Extensions UIImage. You need to add import UIKit also and delete import Foundation

Comment: Can I use it like: `cell.imageView?.resizeToWidth(128).circle`? just it prints that `'UIImageView' does not have a member named 'resizeToWidth'`

Comment: this is an UIImage so cell.imageView!.image =

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74798/discussion-between-orkhan-alizade-and-leonardo-savio-dabus).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a frame width or height independently. You have to set the complete frame. In Objective C it would be something like

```
cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(cell.imageView.frame.origin.x, cell.imageView.frame.origin.y, 100, 100);
```

Comment: But I write it in the Swift. The next error appears: `Value of optional type 'CGFloat?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?`

Comment: I cannot test it here but it is probably something like: cell.imageView?.frame = CGRectMake(x:cell.imageView.frame.origin.x,y:cell.imageView.frame.origin.y,width:100, height:100);

Comment: `Value of optional type 'CGFloat?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?` and `Extraneous argument labels 'x:y:width‌​:height:' in call` errors

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change an attribute of the frame property of any view. You have to provide a totally new frame.

```
cell.imageView?.frame.size.width = 100 //wont work
```

Try doing this -

```
let rect = cell.imageView?.frame;

rect.size.width = 100;

cell.imageView?.frame = rect; //this will work
```

Comment: `'CGRect?' does not have a member named 'size'` error here for the second line

Comment: it failed with the error that I post above in comment

Comment: How is that possible? CGrect has a member size!!! Check here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGRect

Comment: I do not know man =/ I use not TableViewController, but ViewController, just for the info